# Identify movie clip seen in NATGEO Mars Series Episode "Power"

Tags: story-identification, mars

In the Mars Series episode "Power", there is a clip of some astronauts in spacesuits. One is seen getting a handful of dirt in his gloved hand. I remember this movie from way back when. I believe it was sometime in the late 50's or early 60's.

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/mars/episodes/power/ - timecode 00:11:35(ish)

Comment: no reference in the credits?

Comment: I don't see a reference.

Comment: will be among these I bet: http://i.imgur.com/yBmScRK.png

Comment: @NKCampbell - Hehe. Speaking of British Pathé; http://www.britishpathe.com/video/miss-honeywell

Comment: Searching for "blue space suits" yields nothing useful. Except [this](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-0RYZ7A454ZM/UaQ0pqjp8jI/AAAAAAAABY4/vxt9W5-EvAo/s1600/eve+underwear.jpg), but it's for another question.

Comment: I've searched for both 50's sci-fi movies and 60's sci-fi movies (I think 50's is more likely) and made targeted efforts towards 'Mars' in those results to no avail - but, I've only looked at sci-fi possible results, as opposed to more Hammer Horror-esque things like "Devil Woman from Mars" but I suppose that's possible too lol

Comment: Dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143421/old-science-fiction-film-father-and-son-on-space-mission/143423#143423

Answer (score 5):

It's [**Conquest of Space**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_Space), by Byron Haskin (1955).

My picture search for "film 80s blue space suit red planet" led me [here](http://canvas.grolsch.com/film-works/fashion-in-film-space-suits), where some guy discusses fashion in space films. Good read for historical value.

Here's a relevant part of the film:

From Wikipedia summary:

> The storyline concerns the first interplanetary flight to the planet Mars, manned by a crew of five, and launched from Earth orbit near "The Wheel", mankind's first space station. On their long journey to the Red Planet, they encounter various dangers, both from within and without, that nearly destroy the mission.

Comment: Good find. My google-fu failed me.

Comment: Nice job. I too failed in my quest for answers.